# No se guardan los saltos de linea que envia un Textarea en la base de datos

Tags: html, sql-server, textarea

Al momento de enviar un texto en un Textarea que tenga saltos de linea los interpreta con este caracter `↵` pero al momento de almacenarlo en la base de datos no se almacena dicho saltos y el texto termina de corrido.

A continuación envió Screen donde envió los datos y como se termina representando en la base de datos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: con text area te refieres q ue estas intentando desde un PHP o HTML?

Comment: Por lo regular los datagrids ignoran los saltos de línea, si lo visualizas en un textarea probablemente los verías.

Answer (score 0):

puede ser un error de conversion de informacion(generacion Json). en algun lado de proceso de almacenamiento esta perdiendo el caracter. para un salto de linea depende mucho de origen (windows, Unix/linux o mac)

estos tres universos los saltos en linea son diferentes en windows es nueva linea (10) y retorno de carro (13)

tienes que verificar si en tu base de datos estan llegando dichos caracteres en la insercion o actualizacion de datos.. en el siguente caso creamos una tabla y le almacenamos aleatoriamente Tab (ascii 9), Nueva Linea (ascci 10 ) y Retorno de carro (13) y con un split lo separamos

[Ejemplo puedes ver que el almacenamiento de los datos en sql server se realizan sin problemas](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bba3d/3)